# how to add data from cursor to viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cursor

is there a way to add data from cursor to viewpager, I have data in my cursor for example 4 items and I need to place each item on a page how can I do this using cursor and viewpager is it possible?
thanks.

Comment: Yes,ViewPager is connected to ViewPagerAdapter for getting the child Views, You can add new pages / delete pages on ViewPagerAdapter and update the ViewPager by calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: you mean PagerAdapter and how can i link this to a cursor?

Comment: Dint understand your question here. Are you looking for a Auto-Cursor-Update something like CursorAdapter? If yes, that is not feasible. You'd need to manually iterate through Cursor and populate PagerAdapter.

Comment: no I need to add the content of the cursor to the viewpager which mean I need to display the content of my cursor in the viewpager so that each item of my cursor is on a different page.

Comment: In that case, you should be doing : "You'd need to manually iterate through Cursor and populate PagerAdapter."

Comment: yes I've been trying to do that since minutes now thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37062/discussion-between-user-and-gaurav-arora)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you need a PagerAdapter, it will bind your PagerView with data and generate every "item" (every fragment or page) that shows up on the PagerView.

So first override a PagerAdapter, for example:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
```

Then you have to override the method that generates every item on the PagerAdapter, the `instantiateItem()` method. This method gives you an integer argument named **position**, it corresponds to the item number on the list of items that will show on your PagerView. Imagine a book, if every page is an item, the page number is the position.

So according to this position, every item will be different in a way that you must explain to the adapter through your code. To do this, you can use this position to access your list of data and create a correspondence between the list and the page.

Lets say you have a table Person with people names and you retrieve all entries, you create a List that holds all the names data from that cursor. You can now access your list using the item position, for example, `list.get(position)` and by retrieving the data from that particular list item you can create the individual page that you must return on instantiateItem. You can, for example inflate a layout, which contains a TextView called personName, then do something like `personName.setText(list_name.get(position))`. Now return the LayoutView. The Adapter will then create a view for every item on your List.

So you can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> names_list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then store the cursor information on that List (You can do more than one list, and you can do it directly with a cursor using a CursorAdapter, this is just an example) and then instantiate your adapter:

```
MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(context, layout, names_list);
```

For every item on the list, the adapter will run the instantiateItem method and create an item to populate a ViewPager, so now all you have to do is bind the Adapter with your ViewPager:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.activity_search_viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is just an example to kinda explain the idea of how a PagerAdapter works, there is a bit more to this subject than just this. Anyway, once you get confortable with the way things work, you can also check the CursorAdapter, so you can instantiate items directly from cursor data, no need for a list.

Here are some SDK references you should check:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Good luck :)

Comment: hey thanks I've already done it via this tutorial:http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.android.viewpager/src/de/vogella/android/viewpager/ViewPagerActivity.html